# xBehave reporting scenarios as living documentation

Tags: .net, bdd, xunit, xunit.net, xbehave.net

Is it possible to generate automatically a doc file (any format) after the scenarios run?.

How is everyone dealing with "living documentation" when you are using xBehave?